# how do you make a card clickable and move to another page using Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to make a card clickable and move to another page 'ForecastWeather' once clicked.. I'm using Inkwell to make a card clickable but then nothing happens.. what am I doing wrong? I need to make a card clickable and move to the forecastweather page.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing correct but your **Navigation** method is wrong. You need to use `Navigator` to `navigate` between `screens`. Just change your code like below to `Navigate` to another `screen` :

```
InkWell(
        onTap: (){
          Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>LoginScreen()));
        },
        child: Card(
          child: Weather(weather: weatherData),
        ),
      )
```

To deal with the `context` error you need to wrap your **Scaffold** into a **Builder** that will provide a `context` to it's child `widgets`

```
Builder(
          builder: (context) {
            return Scaffold(
              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              appBar: AppBar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                bottom: const TabBar(tabs: [
                  Tab(
                    icon: FaIcon(
                      FontAwesomeIcons.solidSun,
                      color: Colors.orange,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Tab(
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.favorite,
                        color: Colors.pink,
                      )),
                ]),
              ),
              body: TabBarView(
                children: [
                  InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).push(
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => const ABC(),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    child: Card(
                      child: Weather(weather: weatherData),
                    ),
                  ),
                  // SecondTab()
                ],
              ),
            );
          }
        )
```

Comment: I followed your solution and still nothing happens.. just an error message that says " Another exception was thrown: Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator. " any ideas?

Comment: can you share full code of this file I think you are missing something

Comment: Yes, I just shared the full code.

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can navigate by wrapping your widget with `Inkwell` or `GestureDetector`.

```
InkWell(
        onTap: (){
          Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>DashBoardScreen(),),);
        },
        child: Card(
          child:Text('Hello! Navigation using Inkwell.'),
        ),
      )

 GestureDetector(
        onTap: (){
          Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>DashBoardScreen(),),);
        },
        child: Card(
          child:Text('Hello! Navigation using GestureDetector.'),
        ),
      )
```